# Como verificar a mudança de um Array em JS

Tags: javascript, array, angularjs

Eu tenho um vetor de objetos e quero executar uma função quando ele alterar seu valor (adicionando ou removendo os itens).
Estou utilizando o `md-checkbox` do AngularJS com o `checklist-model` para incluir os valores dentro do meu vetor.

Exemplo:

```
  var vetor = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'maça'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      nome: 'laranja'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      nome: 'banana'
    }
  ];

  alterouValor() {
    // minha função
  }
```

Então a partir daí, qualquer valor que adicionasse ou removesse deveria também chamar a função `alterouValor`.

Comment: Olá Felipe. A sua pergunta me fez lembrar que eu tinha um esboço de pergunta pra fazer aqui no SO em relacao a mudanca de estado de array. Nesse seu caso, a mudanda é feita de que forma? Direta ou pelo Angular? Como isso é feito?

Comment: @CmteCardeal Olá. Eu tenho uma tabela com `data-ng-repeat` de objetos (no exemplo que eu dei acima seriam as frutas que eu poderia adicionar), então eu tenho uma `checkbox` para selecionar todos e uma para cada fruta. Quando eu seleciono alguma das `checkbox`, automaticamente o objeto já é adicionado na minha lista que eu defino pelo `checklist-model`.

Não sei se ficou mais claro.